# Using NSString in another function - iOS

Tags: ios, function, nsstring

I have a few values in a function, which get in that function, that I need in another function.

These are the values.

```
  NSString *latitude =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
NSString *longitude =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate: newLocation.timestamp];
```

I need these in another function to send them to my database every time they have found a new location.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using the CLLocationManagerDelegate?

So when a new location is found its send to this method:

```
– (void)locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:
```

from there you can call your method that writes the values to the database and pass you're values in as parameters. E.g.:

```
– (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)locationManager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation {
    NSString *latitude =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate: newLocation.timestamp];

    [self myFuntionThatWritesToDatabaseWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude date:stringFromDate];
}

- (void)myFuntionThatWritesToDatabaseWithLatitude:(NSString *)latitude longitude:(NSString *)longitude date:(NSString *)stringFromDate {
     // write to Database
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This sounds pretty awesome. I'm gonna try this tomorrow, and i will certainly mark this as accepted if it works. Thanx anyways

Comment: Thanks so much! The only thing i need to know is how to do this with a textfield. But i wont bother you with that. Thank you for helping me with this! greets